# NGINX redirect attempts download instead of rendering image

Tags: nginx, php, images

I've got a PHP page that renders a dynamic image

```
/scripts/oem-image.php?brand=$1&sku=$2 break;
```

I'm trying to do a background redirect (keep the original url) from a .jpg link. For instance, if you requested

```
/media/catalog/product/oem-label/honda/3580-hn7-004.jpg
```

it would display the image from the following URL but would still show the above URL in the address bar

```
/scripts/oem-image.php?brand=honda&sku=3580-hn7-004
```

Here's what I've got in the nginx config. The only problem is that when you try to go to the `/media/...` link, it attempts to download the file rather than simple displaying it.

```
location /media/catalog/product/oem-label/ {
  rewrite ^/media/catalog/product/oem-label/(.*)/(.*).jpg$ /scripts/oem-image.php? brand=$1&sku=$2 break;
}
```

---

ADDITIONAL INFO

I'm setting

```
<?php header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); ?>
```

and have also tried

```
<?php header("Content-disposition: inline"); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the right `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers in your application?

Comment: `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`

Comment: If you access /scripts/oem-image.php?brand=honda&sku=3580-hn7-004 directly, does it behave the same?

Comment: Accessing it directly shows the image as intended. It does not attempt to download.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you provide full `/media/catalog/product/oem-label/` location here? I do not see any proxy_pass here. Is the image you download  actually an image?

Comment: @Glueon, I'm not sure about the first part of your question. The result is a php rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch break by last in your redirect

Comment: Could you provide an example, rather?